# How to create project in Kotlin | Android Studio 3.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I am learning Kotlin and i need to create some demos in Kotlin.

Whenever i am going to create new project, i am always getting this -

[image]

Can anybody help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check Include Kotlin support when Create Android Project

Comment: @ShivamKumar I am  NOT getting that screen.

Comment: You can go to File-> New -> New Project... -> One popup window open where you can write your Application name , Company domain and Project location. In this screen below you can see checkbox Include Kotlin support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. File-> New -> New Project
2. Make sure you tick `Include Kotlin Support`

[image]